# Running a project build in iOS5/xcode 4.2 on iOS simulator 4.2/xcode3.2.5

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4, ios5

I had created a project using base sdk 5.0 in xcode 4.2. While creating the project, I had not checked all 3 options that are displayed, when we create the new project on iOS 5.0, namely. storyboard, use ARC and include unit tests. After writing my code, I want to run this on xcode 3.2.5/ iOS 4.2, but it gives an error because iOS 5 uses @autoreleasepool instead of NSAutoreleasePool. How will I run it on iOS4.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using the old main.m?

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
    [pool release];
    return retVal;
}
```

Another thing. "storyboards" and "ARC" are only supported in iOS 5. So this will be a problem too if you want to run this in iOS4.

**summary:**
if u want backward compatibility write your program on the lowest version you want to support and it will be fine. use old main.m, retain instead of strong and no storyboards or ARC and it works on iOS >= 4.

Comment: lets say I am using the old main.m containing NSAutoreleasePool instead of the one using @autoreleasepool. But another problem is related to strong and weak keyword in property declaration. They are only available in sdk 5.0. So, I will have to change them, too. As fas as storyboards and ARC are concerned, I am not using them in sdk 5.0. So, they won;t create any problem in 4.0 or 4.2.

Comment: use retain instead of strong - i see no problem in that. what's now the problem anyway? u know whats wrong and how to solve it.

Comment: the problem is related to backward compatibility. Just by doing this 2 things, will I be able to deploy the code written using iOS5 on iOS4 or 4.2?

Comment: if u want backward compatibility write your program on the lowest version you want to support and it will be fine. use old main.m, retain instead of strong and no storyboards or ARC and it works on iOS >= 4.

Comment: Thanks buddy. This is all I was asking